# Export DynamoDB table to S3 bucket: No subnet found in default VPC. At least one subnet is required

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I need to export DynamoDB table to s3 bucket. I'm using this article: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBPipeline.html.

in Amazon EMR i found error:

__
Cluster: EmrClusterForBackup_2016-10-05T12:33:02Terminated with errorsNo subnet found in default VPC. At least one subnet is required.
__

Maybe someone have faces similar error.  I know the error is like self-explaining, but I'm new to AWS, probably might be missing something, and maybe something obvious.

Anyway, would be thankful for all the points.

[image]

Ivan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Support helped in resolving this issue.

*I needed to add to data pipeline properties subnetid identifier for the EMR cluster to proceed with exporting.*

steps:

- select your pipeline and click on actions -> edit pipeline
- select the resource EmrCluster (EmrClusterForBackup) and add optional field Subnet Id.
- locate subnets for your default VPC and provide it in this field

Answer (score 2):

are there any actual subnets in that default VPC?

**If no:** follow these instructions to create / add one: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html#AddaSubnet

**If yes:** this may be a DynamoDB bug.

Comment: yes there are subnets in default VPC.  If I create Amazon EMR cluster by hand, it goes okay, I see the subnet assigned to cluster and availability zone also.

If I try to export dynamodb table to s3 bucket, EMR cluster created automatically.  And I see this error.

Comment: added image to my question.  that's what I get when trying to export dynamodb table to s3 bucket.